# Docker unable to connect to postgres, but same command works fine when running from containers bash

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When building the docker file, I have the command:

`CMD ["/app/database/updateLocalDocker.sh"]`

The shell script should connect to the postgres service using liquibase but fails with the error ***connection refused*...**

When i comment out the above CMD and run the same script directory from the container via `docker exec -t -i f42c4bbcd95d /bin/bash`, it works fine.

The URL i'm trying to connect to is: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/service_x"`

I have a feeling that it's related to either the service not being started or a network issue, when trying to execute the CMD during the docker-compose build stage.

Any guidance would be much appreicated.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: local.db
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - a

networks:
  a:
    name: a
    external: true
```

Comment: Do you expose your postgre on port 5432 in your running container ?

Comment: I've updated my question with my docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

To access your database from your localhost you need to use the port 15432 instead of 5432.

```
services:
  db:
    image: local.db
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 15432:5432  <--- Here
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - a
```

The first port is your host and the second is the port used in your container.

You can also access it with the container name and the port used in it.

Docker port mapping documentation :
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: It looks like it is an issue with the host/port, as pg_isready is now returning true. I've tried with a combination of localhost, 127.0.0.1 and "db", with all ports without success. It just can't seem to connect.

Comment: Is your host port available ? (Maybe you have another instance of postgresql on this port)

Comment: It should be. When i run the containers bash command after startup, then run the shell script, it works perfectly. But when the script is ran as an entrypoint with docker-compose up, it complains "connection refuse".

It's almost like the entrypoint scripts get executed before host / routing tables are setup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the command in the Dockerfile, you can directly put the command in the docker-compose file and remove `CMD ["/app/database/updateLocalDocker.sh"]`.

docker-compose.yml

```
 version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: local.db
    build:
      context: .
    command: sh -c "<Enter-your-command>"
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - a

networks:
  a:
    name: a
    external: true
```

If you have one command execute
`command: <command>`

OR

If you have more than one command, it should be separated by `&&`.

Syntax:
`sh -c "<command-1> && <command-2> && <command-3>"`